# Start a Messaging Activity in Mesibo

Tags: android, android-fragments, mesibo

I am trying to customize the Mesibo UI in two two fragments. In first tab it will show all the chats and in the second tab all the contacts. Here I want to pass the list of contacts by myself.

My first question is **How can I pass the user name as a list to show the contacts using MesiboUserListFragment**

Second question is how can I implement On User click listener where it will start the Messaging activity where I could customize each message layout.

I have tried in the following way but it doesn't work.

**Activity that implements MesiboUserListFragment.FragmentListener**

```
    @Override
    public boolean Mesibo_onClickUser(String s, long l, long l1) {

    Intent peerMessageIntent = new Intent(MessagingActivity.this,PeerMessageActivity.class);
    peerMessageIntent.putExtra("s", s);
    peerMessageIntent.putExtra("l", l);
    peerMessageIntent.putExtra("l1", l1);
    startActivity(peerMessageIntent);


    return true;
}
```

**PeerMessaging Activity**

```
public class PeerMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_peer_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String s = intent.getStringExtra("s");
    long l = intent.getLongExtra("l", 0);
    long l1 = intent.getLongExtra("l1", 0);

    MesiboMessagingFragment mFragment = new MessagingUIFragment();
    

    Bundle bl = new Bundle();
    bl.putString(MesiboUI.PEER, s);
    bl.putLong(MesiboUI.GROUP_ID, l);
    mFragment.setArguments(bl);

    Log.v("Starting the Transation", "Hereeeeeeeeeeee");

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment).commit();

}
```

}

**MessagingUI Fragment**

```
public class MessagingUIFragment extends MesiboMessagingFragment implements MesiboRecycleViewHolder.Listener {

@Override
public int Mesibo_onGetItemViewType(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, String message) {

    return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_NONE;
}

@Override
public MesiboRecycleViewHolder Mesibo_onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void Mesibo_onBindViewHolder(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder, int viewType, boolean selected, Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, Mesibo.MesiboMessage mesiboMessage) {

}

@Override
public void Mesibo_oUpdateViewHolder(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder, Mesibo.MesiboMessage mesiboMessage) {

}


@Override
public void Mesibo_onViewRecycled(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder) {

}
```

}

**activity_peer_message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PeerMessageActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the UI customization section here, it has everything you are asking

https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/

and

https://mesibo.com/documentation/ui-modules/android/messaging/

mesibo User list fragment works in multiple modes, message list which is the default, and then you can pass mode for different functionalities, refer the source code here.

Refer source code here, https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/UserListFragment.java#L239

As you can see from the source code here, there is MODE_SELECTCONTACT which you can pass and try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply though. I have gone through the documentation but couldn't make it..

1. How to pass the list of User Profiles in the MODE_SELECTCONTACT to show the list of user profiles. 

2. When I click on any of the user from Message List fragment (MODE_MESSAGELIST)  it gives null pointer exception error in the 'com.mesibo.messaging.MessagingActivity' class.

Comment: You should add contacts using userprofile API. Refer to https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/profiles/ 

Also, refer to line 895 in the source code link above.

Comment: Hi, I have asked another question here, if you please help. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698898/mesibo-call-ui-is-not-updating