# Mesibo Call UI is not updating

Tags: android, fragment, messaging, mesibo

I am trying to change the Configuration of Mesibo Call UI. But it's not changing. I tried as follows.

```
MesiboCallConfig mesiboCallConfig = new MesiboCallConfig();
mesiboCallConfig.backgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

I am also having trouble to customize the message bubble and the edit text/file layout at the bottom. I could achieve customizing the send text and message bubble but in case of file transfer I am struggling how to show progress and handling file upload and download in background if the user exit from message fragment. I have tried in the following way.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import com.mesibo.api.Mesibo;
import com.mesibo.messaging.MesiboMessagingFragment;
import com.mesibo.messaging.MesiboRecycleViewHolder;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import static com.mesibo.api.Mesibo.FileInfo.TYPE_IMAGE;

public class CustomMessagingFragment extends MesiboMessagingFragment implements MesiboRecycleViewHolder.Listener, Mesibo.MessageListener {


    @Override
    public int Mesibo_onGetItemViewType(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, String message) {


        try {
            String tag = message.split(" ")[0];
            if (tag.equals("<>")) {
                return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_CUSTOM;
            } else if (tag.equals("^^")) {
                return 2581;
            } else {
                if (messageParams.isIncoming()) {
                    return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_INCOMING;
                } else {
                    return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_OUTGOING;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_OUTGOING;
        }

//        return MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public MesiboRecycleViewHolder Mesibo_onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        //Logger.e("on " + viewType);
        //Log.e("ViewType ", "int " + viewType);
        if (viewType == MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_HEADER) {

        }
        if (MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_CUSTOM == viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_message_layout, viewGroup, false);
            return new SpecialMessageViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_message_show, viewGroup, false);
            return new IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder(v);
        }

//        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onBindViewHolder(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder, int viewType, boolean selected, Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, Mesibo.MesiboMessage mesiboMessage) {

        if (MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_CUSTOM == viewType) {

            SpecialMessageViewHolder IncomingView = (SpecialMessageViewHolder) mesiboRecycleViewHolder;
            IncomingView.totoal_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Calendar var1;
            (var1 = Calendar.getInstance()).setTimeInMillis(mesiboMessage.ts);
            Date var2 = var1.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
            String time = localDateFormat.format(var2);

            IncomingView.mIncomingMessageTV.setText(mesiboMessage.message);
            IncomingView.mTime.setText(time);

        }

        if (MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_INCOMING == viewType) {
            IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder messageViewHolder = (IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder) mesiboRecycleViewHolder;
            messageViewHolder.mOutgoing_total_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageViewHolder.mIncoming_total_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            Calendar var1;
            (var1 = Calendar.getInstance()).setTimeInMillis(mesiboMessage.ts);
            Date var2 = var1.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            String time = localDateFormat.format(var2);

//            messageViewHolder.mIncomingMessageTV.setText(mesiboMessage.message);
            if (mesiboMessage.file == null) {
                messageViewHolder.mIncomingMessageTV.setText(mesiboMessage.message);
            } else {
                messageViewHolder.mIncomingMessageTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                messageViewHolder.mIncomingMessageIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url = mesiboMessage.file.message;
                Log.v("File Info In Recycle: ", url.substring(0, url.length()-1));
                messageViewHolder.mIncomingMessageIV.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url.substring(0, url.length()-1)));
            }
            messageViewHolder.mIncomingTime.setText(time);

        }

        if (MesiboRecycleViewHolder.TYPE_OUTGOING == viewType) {
            IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder messageViewHolder = (IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder) mesiboRecycleViewHolder;
            messageViewHolder.mOutgoing_total_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            messageViewHolder.mIncoming_total_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Calendar var1;
            (var1 = Calendar.getInstance()).setTimeInMillis(mesiboMessage.ts);
            Date var2 = var1.getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            String time = localDateFormat.format(var2);

//            messageViewHolder.mOutgoingMessageTV.setText(mesiboMessage.message);
            if (mesiboMessage.file == null) {
                messageViewHolder.mOutgoingMessageTV.setText(mesiboMessage.message);
            } else {
                messageViewHolder.mOutgoingMessageTV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                messageViewHolder.mOutgoingMessageIV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url = mesiboMessage.file.message;
                Log.v("File Info In Recycle: ", url.substring(0, url.length()-1));
                messageViewHolder.mOutgoingMessageIV.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url.substring(0, url.length()-1)));
            }

            messageViewHolder.mOutgoingTime.setText(time);
            messageViewHolder.mSendStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            switch (mesiboMessage.status) {
                case 0:
                    messageViewHolder.mSendStatus.setText("Sending..");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    messageViewHolder.mSendStatus.setText("Sent");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    messageViewHolder.mSendStatus.setText("Delivered");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    messageViewHolder.mSendStatus.setText("Read");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void Mesibo_oUpdateViewHolder(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder, Mesibo.MesiboMessage mesiboMessage) {

    }


    @Override
    public void Mesibo_onViewRecycled(MesiboRecycleViewHolder mesiboRecycleViewHolder) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean Mesibo_onMessage(Mesibo.MessageParams messageParams, byte[] bytes) {
        return super.Mesibo_onMessage(messageParams, bytes);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMediaButtonClicked(int i) {
        super.onMediaButtonClicked(i);
    }

    public static class SpecialMessageViewHolder extends MesiboRecycleViewHolder {
        View mViewIncomingMessage;
        TextView mIncomingMessageTV;
        TextView mTime;
        CardView totoal_view;


        public SpecialMessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            totoal_view = v.findViewById(R.id.cardview_recive_messsage);
            mIncomingMessageTV = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_msg_recive);
            mTime = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_recive_time);
            mViewIncomingMessage = v;
        }
    }

    public static class IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder extends MesiboRecycleViewHolder{
        View mViewIncomingMessage;
        ImageView mIncomingMessageIV, mOutgoingMessageIV;
        TextView mIncomingMessageTV, mOutgoingMessageTV;
        TextView mIncomingTime, mOutgoingTime, mSendStatus;
        CardView mIncoming_total_view, mOutgoing_total_view;


        public IncomingOutgoingMessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mIncoming_total_view = v.findViewById(R.id.cardview_recive_messsage);
            mOutgoing_total_view = v.findViewById(R.id.cardview_send_messsage);


            mIncomingMessageTV = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_msg_recive);
            mOutgoingMessageTV = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_msg_send);


            mIncomingTime = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_recive_time);
            mOutgoingTime = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_send_time);
            mSendStatus = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_msg_send_status);

            mIncomingMessageIV = v.findViewById(R.id.imageview_msg_recive);
            mOutgoingMessageIV = v.findViewById(R.id.imageview_msg_send);

            mViewIncomingMessage = v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create new config, you should instead get the config and modify.

change

```
MesiboCallConfig mesiboCallConfig = new MesiboCallConfig();
```

To

```
MesiboCallConfig mesiboCallConfig = MesiboCall.getInstance().getConfig():
```

Comment: Sorry to say that it doesn't work. It changes the default color to another color. It always shows a deep blue color irrespective of the color passed. I have tried in the following way. I have added this in MainApplication, onCreate function. 
MesiboCallConfig mesiboCallConfig = MesiboCall.getInstance().getConfig();
mesiboCallConfig.backgroundColor = R.color.colorPrimaryDark;
And initializing the call as follows.
MesiboCall.getInstance().call(getApplicationContext(), Mesibo.random(), f, false);

Comment: You have to pass the ARGB color code like 0xFFCC0000

Comment: Yes, Now it worked as expected. Will you please help me how to change the message bubble color using MessagingActivityNew class? 
Also how can I change the color of circular send button in Image Edit activity? 
What basically I want to change the default primary color.

Comment: Since it worked, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark. 

You can similarly use getConfig on MesiboUI, you will find fields which you can change. The entire source code is here so easy to find out what to change

https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/master/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MesiboConfiguration.java